# Create curved Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

it is possible in WPF to create a control (e.g. button) looks like this?

[image: curved control]

Actually, I want to draw 4 buttons so that they are positioned as a circle.

Comment: It is possible. Have you tried anything? You could use a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx) as a Button's Content.

Comment: Not yet because I have completely no idea how to start. Currently I only know how to rotate and skew.

Comment: You might read [Customizing the Appearance of an Existing Control by Creating a ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The following XAML might give you a rough idea how to start with a Path in the Button's Template. However, it misses essential things like visual feedback for the MouseOver and Pressed states.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="SegmentGeometry">M 5,0 A 10,10 0 0 0 15,10 L 15,15 A 15,15 0 0 1 0,0 Z</StreamGeometry>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate">
            <Viewbox>
                <Path Fill="Transparent" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
                      Data="{StaticResource SegmentGeometry}"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
        <Button.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="135"/>
        </Button.LayoutTransform>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is there another way to define the figure instead of the coordinates set in "SegmentGeometry", maybe in a more dynamically way to possible encapsulate this in a scalable control?

Comment: Of course there is. Start reading here: [Geometry Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Working with coordinates / path / geometry is not straight forward. Try using [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) from Microsoft. It is a UI like Photoshop, but just for Xaml.:)