# curved WPF control

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I have a curved control (e.g. ScrollBar) like this?

[image: curved ScrollBar]

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179562/create-curved-control-in-wpf) question, but it has no useful information.

Answer (score 0):

This could give you some idea how to do it.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
      <PathGeometry.Figures>
        <PathFigureCollection>
          <PathFigure StartPoint="10,100">
            <PathFigure.Segments>
              <PathSegmentCollection>
                <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="200,200" Point2="300,100" />
              </PathSegmentCollection>
            </PathFigure.Segments>
          </PathFigure>
        </PathFigureCollection>
      </PathGeometry.Figures>
    </PathGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

for more details please this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/shapes-and-basic-drawing-in-wpf-overview/%22link%22).

Comment: Is there any way to put a control (e.g. Grid) into a Path?